# Overriden function getting hiden even after a dynamic cast (upcast)

Tags: c++, casting, dynamic-cast, static-cast

I started to learn about dynamic cast and how it uses the RTTI to determine the type of the object for a downcast.
In this example, I did an upcast, from a derived class to the base class.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo()
    {
        cout<<"Base"<<endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        cout<<"Derived"<<endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Derived* d = new Derived();

    Base* b = dynamic_cast<Base*>(d);        //(1)

    cout<<typeid(b).name()<<endl;
    b->foo();

    return 0;

}
```

The program prints:

```
PBase
Derived
```

For me:

- In the compilation, the compiler creates a vTable for the base class, where we have a pointer to the RTTI "table", and a pointer to the Base::foo function.
- In the execution time, when the program arrives to the line (1), He creates a _vptrBase pointer who points to this vTable.

My question is: how is comes that the program print "Derived" while we are calling the foo function? Why It doesn't call the Base::foo function?

Comment: `Base* b = dynamic_cast<Base*>(d);` is equivalent to just `Base* b = d;`. This line doesn't touch vtable pointer inside of the class. It was pointing to the vtable for `Derived` when the object was created (because it's its type), and it continues to point to that vtable after the cast.

Comment: if you don't want that, then don't make `foo` virtual. see [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5667cab411dfccc5)

Comment: if you do want virtual, but need call `Base::foo`, then call it explicitly `b->Base::foo();`. see [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f477ec9f5511fec3)

Comment: This is what polymorphism is for. You can have pointer to base class and call methods defined for derived versions. Better example would have an array of Base pointers and multiple versions of  Derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) (bold is mine):

> Virtual functions are member functions whose behavior can be
> overridden in derived classes. As opposed to non-virtual functions,
> the overriding behavior is preserved even if there is no compile-time
> information about the actual type of the class. That is to say, **if a
> derived class is handled using pointer or reference to the base class,
> a call to an overridden virtual function would invoke the behavior
> defined in the derived class**. Such a function call is known as virtual
> function call or virtual call.